# Django migration error - ValueError: Invalid model reference 'apps.auth.Permission'

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I run python `manage.py makemigrations users` I get

`ValueError: Invalid model reference 'apps.auth.Permission'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.`

my django file structure is

```
.
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── apps
│   └── users
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── forms.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── siteconfig
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── virtualenv
```

some relevant variables from `settings.py` are

#### settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

#### users/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    kindle_email_address = models.EmailField(_('kindle email address'))
```

#### users/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.users'
```

The full stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/utils.py", line 11, in make_model_tuple
    app_label, model_name = model.split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 168, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 128, in _detect_changes
    self.old_apps = self.from_state.concrete_apps
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 214, in concrete_apps
    self.apps = StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models, ignore_swappable=True)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.render_multiple([*models.values(), *self.real_models])
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 308, in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 579, in render
    return type(self.name, bases, body)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 156, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1576, in contribute_to_class
    super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, **kwargs)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 318, in contribute_to_class
    lazy_related_operation(resolve_related_class, cls, self.remote_field.model, field=self)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 80, in lazy_related_operation
    return apps.lazy_model_operation(partial(function, **kwargs), *model_keys)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 78, in <genexpr>
    model_keys = (make_model_tuple(m) for m in models)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/utils.py", line 20, in make_model_tuple
    "must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'." % model
ValueError: Invalid model reference 'apps.auth.Permission'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.
```

Comment: Do you use `apps.auth` anywhere in your codebase? Note that adding `apps` to the Python path with `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))` isn't a good idea. It means that you can import the `users` app with `import apps.users` or `import users`, which can lead to bugs. You shouldn't normally need an `__init__.py` inside the directory that contains `manage.py`.

Comment: I do not use apps.auth in my code. I do use `django.contrib.auth`

Answer (score 0):

This resolved itself by uninstalling and reinstalling Django.

I think it had to do something with having an app named 'auth' that I deleted previously.